# Is there a Apps Script function to export the viewer information present in the Activity Dashboard into a separate GSheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Actually I was trying to set a repository kind of a thing with a count of number of views on my document everyday. This information is present in Activity Dashboard but I was not able to figure out a way to extract the information present in Activity Dashboard into a separate GSheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The closest to the Activity Dashboard is the [Google Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity)

- You can use the method [Method: activity.query](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query)
- To see the ativity for a particular file, specify the parameter `itemName` setting it to `items/ID_OF_YOUR_FILE`
- to get familiar with the structure of the response body - test with the `Try this API` feature
- Later on, to incorporate this feature in Apps Script [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) in your Apps Script editor the [Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive-activity)

Small sample:

```js
function listDriveActivity() {
  var fileId = "XXX";
  var request = {itemName: "items/" + fileId};
  var response = DriveActivity.Activity.query(request);
  Logger.log("The first activity: " + response.activities[0]);
}
```

The documentation contains an extended [sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive-activity#get_activity_in_google_drive) for showing what is possible with the Drive Activity API.

UPDATE

The method above returns among others editing activities, but not viewing activities.

**To track viewing activities, as a domain admin you can use the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive).**

- To use it in Apps Script, enable it under `Resources -> Advanced Google Services`.
- Use the method `AdminReports.Activities.list()`.
- Specify in the query the application you are interested in (in your case `drive`) and additional query parameters like the activity (`view`) or the `id` of the document you are interested in.
- Loop through the results and retrieve the fields of interest (e.g. `actor.email`).

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var views = AdminReports.Activities.list("all", "drive", {eventName: "view", filters: "doc_id==XXXXX"}).items;
  for ( var i = 0; i< views.length; i++){
    Logger.log(views[i].actor.email);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am very new to App script and how Google Drive API works. I did try to implement the small sample but it is not giving who all actually viewed that doc. To be more precise I just want to see names of who accessed that document. Can you please help me setting up a code or something so that whenever I run that code I can get names of people who viewed that doc.

Comment: Unfortunately the viewers are not returned  by Drive activity, I will update my answer showing how obtain this kind of information with the Reports API.