# Get Google Drive video view count from Apps Script API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a series of videos uploaded to a specific Google Drive folder, and I'd like to get the view count for each video/file. Literally as simple as "file_id" "10 views".

From extensive research, it seems this is quite simply impossible within Google Apps Script today? [Per this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599655/is-there-a-apps-script-function-to-export-the-viewer-information-present-in-the), both the Drive API and the Drive Activity API only report edit or comment activity, while view activity is ignored. The Reports API does support this, but only for users with Admin access in an Enterprise account (not for us plebes who just want to know view counts on our own files).

And per [this Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), it seems that onOpen() triggers don't run for views (which blocks a "view_count + 1 on open of this specific file" sort of analytics).

Before I give up, I figured I'd run it past this brilliant community: am I missing anything? Is there some way to get view count on videos stored and accessed through Google Drive?

Comment: Try going to issues and make a feature request.  You will find the links in support section of documenation for Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You are correct in your findings that you can not get video view count information through the Drive API. You must use the Admin SDK to obtain this information.*

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Google Drive component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106), with the `Feature Request` template.